# java read Excel column name

Tags: java, excel

I have Excel sheets I used apache POI to read the doc, now I have a problem as I have many sheets the column index is changing.
is there any method to get the column
 name instead of column number?

```
String name =sheets.getRow(choosenRow).getCell(choosenCell).getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: By column name you mean things like `A`, `B` `C` etc

Comment: @mona do these columns have headers? example: First Name, Last Name, Employee ID, ....

Comment: @PaulWakhungu no, I mean the columns header

Comment: @alhinai-hamed yes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
int colNum = -1;                      // what you need
String searchingCol = "Last Name";    // what you are searching for
String colHeader;                     // what is found in each column

do {
    colNum++;                         // incrementing to move to the next column

    // get the header name
    colHeader = sheets.getRow(0).getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue();    

    if (searchingCol.equals(colHeader)) 
         break;                       // exit the loop once the column is found

} while(!colHeader.equals(""));       // loop back only if the the file has more columns
```

**Note that this was not tested**, and to be frank with you, I've never used Apache POI before.
Try to see if there is columnIterator, which can be useful.